# How to extend session timeout in PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, session-cookies

In PHPMyAdmin, the default `LoginCookieValidity` is 1440 seconds.  I changed it in Settings > Fetaurues to 360000.

Also to make sure that the change remains permanent, in `config.inc.php` I added

```
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 360000
```

But the session still expires after few minutes, which is very annoying. I'm wondering how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Create or edit your php.ini file and set this variable value in it:

> session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

The integer is in seconds. 500000 seconds is 5.7 days. Then restart apache.

Comment: I did this. But still have the issue.

Comment: Yep, agree to this that this method does not work at all.